# Drawing a rounded triangle in Blend

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I am looking to draw an equilateral triangle with rounded corners in Expression Blend, kind of like the radius of the rectangle behaves.

I am thinking along the lines of drawing a circle/arc at each end-point and clipping, but this is cumbersome.

Is there a shape that can do this or do you have any other ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It may be a little late, but just in case someone is trying to do the same...

I was trying to do the same, struggling with the lines in blen... I got discouraged and finally did it in Adobe Illustrator, then import my illustrator file in blend... IT WORKED! :D.

Here is a basic Rounded Triangle you can use and resize as you need with the width and height

```
 <Grid x:Name="Root">
    <Path Data="M42.6987,213C26.1987,213,19.5187,201.349,27.8537,187.109L115.1947,37.891C123.5307,23.651,137.1687,23.651,145.5047,37.891L232.8457,187.109C241.1807,201.349,234.4997,213,217.9997,213L42.6987,213z" Fill="White" Canvas.Left="-0.5" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeMiterLimit="10" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Canvas.Top="-0.5" Width="45" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" />
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line with an arc at each end point. You can then group all these three shapes and play along from there.